# Use a supplemental .config file just for a web application

Tags: development, visual-studio, solution-package, web-config

I'm trying to add a section into the `web.config` of a SharePoint 2010 application and I created a `webconfig.myname.xml` in the \14\CONFIG folder. I then ran the following command to apply the changes:

```
stsadm -o copyappbincontent
```

The content was added TO ALL web applications config files.

I don't want that, I just want it for one web application.

How can I do it? I think its possible to [do it programmatically](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/01/21/web.config-modifications-with-a-sharepoint-feature.aspx) but that involves writing the XML in code and I don't really like it.

P.S. Also, a thing that's not clear is what should be `myname` in `webconfig.myname.xml`? The solution name, the application name? (I'm currently using the solution name).

Comment: `SPWebConfigModifications` are the way to go. Yes that means you will need to specify your `XML` within your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually used a programmatic approach and created the necessary steps in code, but by having the modifications serialized/deserialized in/from a XML file similar to `web.config`.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out : http://stsadmwebconfig.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The myname in the file name could be whatever you want, SP will look at supplemental file (webconfig.*.xml) in the CONFIG folder. Make sure it's unique to avoid any conflicts with others solutions.

We currently use a [programmatically approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx) for this and we have some issues with the ApplyWebConfigModifications() function. One of them is the one you described, when we apply a web config modification to the WebApplication directly, it apply it to all WebApplication.

Comment: You apply the web config modifications directly to the collection of WebConfigModifications of the web application?! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.webconfigmodifications.aspx Why do you say you can't specify a WebApp?

Comment: @moontear , sorry, yes you can apply directly to the WebApplication, but it will be applied to all Web Application config files. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No it will not be applied to all web applications, that doesn't make sense. When I add something to the `WebConfigModifications` of WebApp1, my WebApp2's web.config remains unchanged. What **does** happen is that SharePoint updates the web.config of WebApp2 (i.e. it saves it), but there are no changes from WebApp1 in WebApp2's web.config.

Comment: @moontear, in our scenario it apply to all web.config. Microsoft Support have acknowledge this situation, but I assume we are doing something different fron typical scenario. Hope it will work for JohnDoDo